# How to test Angular Factory Objects using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine

The problem I'm trying to solve is the ability to test my factory using Jasmine.

Below is a copy of my app and factory:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('service', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCustomers: function (callback) {
            $http.get('/Home/Customers').success(callback);
        },
        getProfile: function (callback, viewModel) {

            $http.post('/Home/Profiles', JSON.stringify(viewModel), {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).success(callback);
        }
    };
});
```

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I have also setup jasmine but I'm having trouble testing the above "getCustomers" and "getProfile".

Below is my current attempt:

```
  describe("getCustomers", function (service) {
      beforeEach(module('service'));
         describe('getCustomers', function () {
            it("should return a list of customers", inject(function(getCustomers){
              expect(getCustomers.results).toEqual(["david", "James", "Sam"]);
         }))
      })
  });
```

This would be really helpful if someone could provide an example of how to test both "getCustomers" and "getProfile" in two separete tests.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

You can mock the Http GET request and test the service like this

```
describe("getCustomers", function (service) {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var service, httpBackend;
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            service = $injector.get('service');
        })
    });

    describe('getCustomers', function () {
        it("should return a list of customers", inject(function () {
            httpBackend.expectGET('/Home/Customers').respond(['david', 'James', 'Sam']);
            service.getCustomers(function (result) {
                expect(result).toEqual(["david", "James", "Sam"]);
            });
            httpBackend.flush();
        }))
    })
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4s6y5/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your response.

Comment: I still get this error: 

getCustomers encountered a declaration exception.
ReferenceError: module is not defined in http://localhost:64550/Content/spec.js

Comment: @Mark Have a look at the working demo I created for you and you should be able to compare it with your solution.

Comment: Hi, I did that but still couldn't get it working.
Seems to be something to do with how I've setup the spec runner.

Comment: I've now got this error with the spec runner:

Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: [$injector:modulerr]